# Função sendo executada antes de receber o valor no ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho o seguinte checkbox:

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="anuncio.checkouCarimbo" (click)="checkouAnuncio()" name="checksegundoAnuncio"
    class="example-margin checkFoto">
</mat-checkbox>
```

A função chamada pelo checkbox ao ser clicada:

```
  checkouAnuncio(){
    for(let i=0;i<this.anuncios.length;i++){
      if(this.anuncios[i].checkouCarimbo == true){
        this.habilitaCarimbar = true;
        return;
      }else{
        this.habilitaCarimbar = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Meu objetivo é percorrer o array anuncios e se em alguma posição o checkouCarimbo for true, setar o campo this.habilitaCarimbar, porém ao realizar o click é chamado a função e só depois é setado no ngModel, portanto minha lógica é quebrada. Há alguma forma de receber o valor primeiro e depois executar a função ou segue essa ordem mesmo?

Comment: Vc deveria escutar o evento de change inves do click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Criei um teste no StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sak5da

No template `(click)="checkouAnuncio()"` passa o anuncio ao clicar e não usa mais ngModel:

```
`<mat-checkbox [checked]="anuncio.checkouCarimbo" (click)="checkouAnuncio(anuncio)" name="checksegundoAnuncio" class="example margin checkFoto"> </mat-checkbox>`
```

No TS, a função modifica o valor do checkbox:

```
checkouAnuncio(checkboxClicked){
      checkboxClicked.checkouCarimbo = !checkboxClicked.checkouCarimbo;

      for(let i=0;i<this.anuncios.length;i++){
         if(this.anuncios[i].checkouCarimbo == true){
         this.habilitaCarimbar = true;
         return;
         }else{
           this.habilitaCarimbar = false;
         }
      }
  }
```

Fiz uma modificação na função, fica a seu critério utiliza-la pois sua função também está correta, segue:

```
checkouAnuncio(checkboxClicked){
      checkboxClicked.checkouCarimbo = !checkboxClicked.checkouCarimbo;
      this.habilitaCarimbar = this.anuncios.filter(anuncio=>anuncio.checkouCarimbo).length > 0;
  }
```

Comment: Não é o que eu preciso. O habilitaCarimbar deve ser true se pelo menos um anuncio tiver o anuncio.checkouCarimbo true. E é através do ngModel que é trocado o true/false desse checkbox

Comment: Seu problema está na ordem apenas? Quer que execute a função antes que o checkbox fique "checkado"?

Comment: A função está sendo executada antes que é habilitado, ai a variavel habilitaCarimbar fica false,

Comment: Ve se é isso que vc precisava agora, modifiquei a resposta adicionando um link pra uma demo

Comment: Vou tentar quando tiver um tempo e te retorno se deu certo